# How to Get Data from another collection in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example, my teacher collection documents look like:

```
{ _id: new ObjectId("64fee9b54273ac223441225"), teacherid: '64f1d72a4331bc8fc4c5930f', name: 'Jackly' }
```

and the users collection documents look like:

```
{ _id: new ObjectId("64f1d72a4331bc8fc4c5930f"), name: 'Mark' }
```

How can I get the name from users collection by the teacherid in the teacher collection? in MongoDB?

```
const studentData = await Teacher.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "_id": "64f1d72a4331bc8fc4c5930f"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "teacherid",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "student"
        }
    },
    {
        $unset: "name"
    }
]);
```

Comment: Add the `package.json` file to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @xgqfrms, I don't see this question related to "package.json". This is just a pure MongoDB query with joining another collection.

Comment: the problem is to convert the string to objectid  before compairing

Comment: do i need to use ObjectId to do that right?

Comment: @cmgchess Well i did  "_id": new ObjectId("64f1d72a4331bc8fc4c5930f") but getting as empty array in respnse

Comment: im not sure about ur datastructure but here is an example https://mongoplayground.net/p/bpB8UM5_X5V  or even https://mongoplayground.net/p/b-O8SWxRqBv

Comment: @YongShun The MongoDB version is important for reproducing the issue. Different versions may have different APIs.

Comment: His schemas seems to be incorrectly designed

Comment: @Suleyman Which. schema  i can show you

Comment: @xgqfrms Im using "mongoose": "^7.5.0",

Comment: Please post your teacher schema. It looks like you are storing `teacherid` as a string in your teacher schema but it should be either an ObjectId with a Ref to the User collection or just the ObjectId. The former would allow you to use Mongoose populate method. The latter would still allow for an aggregate query. Also, should the teacherid not maybe be called userid?

Comment: @cmgchess Hi! Your answer works fine! Thanks you, Can you please create answer on my post and i will mark it as an answer

Comment: @James there is another alternative posted that as well. but it would be better to keep all in 1 format so you dont run into these issues. especially if u are using mongoose u can crceate the schemas accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is that the two fields you are trying to compare are of 2 types. One is a string other is ObjectID. I would recommend to have both of them a single type (preferrably ObjectID) when storing so you don't have to do these intermediate transformations.

however there are a couple of ways of doing this

1. Transforming the `teacherid` to `ObjectID` and then `$lookup`. This will however have the `teacherid` as an ObjectID in the queried result. If you dont want it that way you might have to do an `$addFields` again and convert back to string

```js
db.teacher.aggregate([
  { $match: { teacherid: "64f1d72a4331bc8fc4c5930f" } },
  { $addFields: { teacherid: { $toObjectId: "$teacherid" } } },
  { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "teacherid", foreignField: "_id", as: "student" } },
  { $unset: "name" }
])
```

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b-O8SWxRqBv)

2. Transforming the `teacherid` to ObjectID in the lookup pipeline itself and compairing

```js
db.teacher.aggregate([
  { $match: { "teacherid": "64f1d72a4331bc8fc4c5930f" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: { teacherIdStr: "$teacherid" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: [ "$_id", { $toObjectId: "$$teacherIdStr" } ] }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "student"
    }
  },
  { $unset: "name" }
])
```

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bpB8UM5_X5V)

3. Or convert the foreign field ObjectID to string and match

```js
db.teacher.aggregate([
  { $match: { "teacherid": "64f1d72a4331bc8fc4c5930f" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: { teacherIdStr: "$teacherid" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: { 
            $expr: { $eq: [ { $toString: "$_id" }, "$$teacherIdStr" ] } 
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "student"
    }
  },
  { $unset: "name" }
])
```

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4Ca3U73da4n)

Answer (score 2):

### Here is a quick fix solution

1. change the string id `teacherid` to a `ObjectId`

```bash
$ mongo

# replace the `YOUR_DATABASE_NAME` with your real database name.
> use YOUR_DATABASE_NAME

# update Teacher collection ✅
> db.Teacher.update(
  {"teacherid" : "64f1d72a4331bc8fc4c5930f"},
  {
    $set: {"teacherid" : ObjectId("64f1d72a4331bc8fc4c5930f")}
  });
```

2. then use `teacherid` as the match key

```bash
> db.Teacher.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "teacherid": ObjectId("64f1d72a4331bc8fc4c5930f")
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "user",
            localField: "teacherid",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "student"
        }
    },
    {
        $unset: "name"
    }
]).pretty();
```

### test ✅

> screenshot

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to use the MongoDB aggregation framework to perform a lookup between the "teacher" and "users" collections based on the "teacherid" field. However, there are a few issues with your current aggregation pipeline. Here's the corrected version of your aggregation query:

```js
const studentData = await Teacher.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "_id": new ObjectId("64f1d72a4331bc8fc4c5930f") // Convert the ID to ObjectId
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "teacherid",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "student"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$student" // Unwind the "student" array
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "student.name": 1 // Project the "name" field from the "student" subdocument
        }
    }
]);

console.log(studentData);
```

Here's an explanation of the changes made:

1. In the `$match` stage, you need to convert the `_id` value to an ObjectId using `new ObjectId()` to match the correct document in the "teacher" collection.
2. After the `$lookup` stage, you have an array called "student" that contains the matching user document. To access the "name" field within the "student" subdocument, you need to use the `$unwind` stage to destructure the array.
3. Finally, you can use the `$project` stage to project only the "name" field from the "student" subdocument.

Now, `studentData` should contain the "name" field from the "users" collection for the specified teacher ID in the "teacher" collection.

Comment: I get empty array in response